# One HyperLink on the menu is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, and it is a one page site. However, I used an external link at the nav menu. And I don't understand why is not working.

if you try to go by the url stright it works
http://www.neevasoft.com/docasnovo/acervo.html

But when I'm at the index.html, it doesn't work.

you can chaeck it at:

http://www.neevasoft.com/docasnovo

HTML

```
<div class="body-inner">
<!-- Header start -->
<header id="header" class="navbar-fixed-top main-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <!-- Logo start -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">
                        <img class="img-responsive"  src="images\logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </a>   

                </div><!--/ Logo end -->

                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse clearfix" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">A Empresa</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#historia">História</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Participações</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Renovada</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="acervo.html">Acervo</a></li>
                        <!--li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li-->

                    </ul>

                </nav><!--/ Navigation end -->

            </div><!--/ Col end -->
        </div><!--/ Row end -->
    </div><!--/ Container end -->
</header><!--/ Header end -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably your Javascript code is blocking the execution of normal href attribute. You can do it something like this:

```
<li><a class="page-scroll" href="acervo.html" onClick="window.location='acervo.html'">Acervo</a></li>
```

Inline onClick tag prevails over the Javascript click functions you have set in your document.

Comment: Thanks! It Worked!

Comment: Hey, Ghulam Ali, I'm having problems with the toggle menu, I need it to uncollapse after I click in a link from the onepage. For example #contact.
Any Ideas?